# mysql database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I am new to asp.net. How do I write the codes for MySQl database using asp.net?

Currently, I found this and I think it is not enough to connect the database.

```
SqlConnection con = null
SqlCommand cmd = null
SqlDataReader rdr
```

From what i know they uses public class as well which is similar to java. However, I am not too sure about how it goes.

I would need the codes to define the variables and together with the command statement. Replying to me is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at google gives the following post on developerfusion:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4596/how-to-access-a-mysql-database-with-net/